# Json child of child is being set as undefined in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filesystems

#### Details

Whenever I run the JS file and try `console.log(DB.other.Clay)` it prints undefined.
Im using the built in Node JS module `fs` because I have been told it would perform better with large Json files. It also throws an error when I try and access `DB.other.Clay.buildings`

##### The code

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');

fs.readFile('./conquestDB/res.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
    DB = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(DB.other.Clay)
})
```

##### Json file (highly condensed, the original file has over 400k lines

```json
{
  "other": {
    "Clay": {
       "walls": {...},
       "buildings": {
         "mine": 838,
         "missile_silo": 2,
         "anti_missile_wall": 611,
         "silo_pad_mk2": 8,
         "silo_pad": 8,
         "sign": 69,
         "storage": 462,
         "lab": 299,
         "house": 91,
         "camp": 594,
         "rift": 8,
         "walls": 37681,
         "fortifier": 115
       },
       "count": 61983,
       "locations": {...}
    }
  }
}
```

I do not understand why I am unable to access these Json objects and I am very new to Json in Javascript so please explain it thoroughly.

###### Best regards, FlyingPig525

Comment: What does it say when you just log `DB`? Does it show the JSON you are expecting?

Comment: If your data really looked like what you posted, you would not get that error.

Comment: What does `console.log(DB.other)` show?

Comment: My guess is the actual data includes an array that you've left out of the sample.

Comment: @Ivar it prints all 400k lines in the json file

Comment: @Pointy would you like me to post the entire file?

Comment: probably doesn't look like that

Comment: @FlyingPigGD I ran your code with your example and it works. It has to be your data file or location of the file.

Comment: @Barmar it prints the Json file, and using the vscode search and replace function doesnt show any arrays, so if there is one i do not know of it.

Comment: maybe `Clay` is inside another key object

Comment: @LarsFlieger I know the file and location are correct because if I just print the db variable it prints the whole file.

Comment: @ChrisG `Clay` is shown as a child to `other` in vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to debug this

Work your way down the "tree" of data

Start with this:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');

fs.readFile('./conquestDB/res.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
    DB = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(Object.keys(DB))
})
```

Make sure that long list of keys contains "other"

If so, then advance to the next step:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');

fs.readFile('./conquestDB/res.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
    DB = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(Object.keys(DB.other))
})
```

Check if that list of keys includes "Clay".

I suspect you have an extra layer somewhere, that you haven't noticed.

Comment: I will try this right now